# How to use Fast Fourier Transform to execute convolution of matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, fft, ifft

I need to add many big 3D arrays (with a shape of 500x500x500) together and want to speed up the process by using multiplication in the Fourier space. The problem is that I don't get the same answer when multiplying in the Fourier space compared to simply adding the matrix.

To test it out, I wrote a minimal example trying to make it work but the answer is not what I expected. Either my math knowledge is wrong or I am not using the function correctly.

Below is the simplest code showing what I am trying to do:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.asarray(((1,2),(2,3)))
d = np.asarray(((1,4),(1,5)))

print("Transform")
Nc = np.fft.rfft2(c)
Nd = np.fft.rfft2(d)

print("Inverse")
Nnc = np.fft.irfft2(Nc)
Nnd = np.fft.irfft2(Nd)

print("Somme")
S = np.dot(Nc, Nd)
print(np.fft.irfft2(S))
```

When I print S, I get the result:

```
[[6, 28],[10,46]]
```

But from what I understood about the Fourier space, multiplication would mean addition outside of the Fourier space so I should get `S = c + d`?

Am I doing something wrong using the FFT function or is my assumption that S should equal c plus d wrong?

Comment: @yatu: A convolution with a large(-ish) kernel is expensive to compute in the spatial domain. It is cheaper to compute the FFT for the image and the kernel, do element-wise multiplication, then inverse transform the result. Of course element-wise addition of the array elements is faster in the spatial domain.

Comment: Yes agree that when having to compute a convolution could be faster in the Fourier domain, as it equates to multiplying having taken the FFT. However in the general case it may not be the best idea. Thanks for pointing out though, forgot about this rule for a moment

Answer (score 1):

There is a little misunderstanding here:

Multiplication in Fourier space corresponds to [**convolution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) in the spatial domain and not to addition.

There is no way to speed up addition in that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute `c+d` through the Fourier domain, you'd have to add the two spectra, not multiply them:

```
np.fft.irfft2(Nc+Nd) == c+d  # (up to numerical precision)
```

Of course, this is much slower than simply adding the matrices in the spatial domain.

As [@Florian said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54579284/7328782), it is convolution that can be sped up by multiplying in the spatial domain.